# xfreedrp does not work with dual screen?

Tags: 16.04, rdp, x11rdp

I am running xfreedrp on Ubuntu 16.04 connecting to Windows 10.
Everything goes fine if I run $~: xfreerdp -f -u -p ip.of.target.pc

Now I am trying to get dual monitor working and the /monitor command need me to do $~: xfreerdp -f -multimon -monitors:0,1 -u -p /v:ip.of.target.pc
I got error:

```
/v -> /v:/v /port:10
loading channel cliprdr
connect: No such file or directory
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
```

If I do not specify using `/v:`, then I get error:`error: server hostname was not specified with /v:<server>[:port]`

Answer (score 0):

So I think it is some issue with how xfreerdp parsing the command.
I fixed the issue with:
`xfreerdp /v:ip.of.target.pc /u:user /multimon -f /fonts --plugin`